# Passing String Values between Activities using intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I understand how to pass string values from the MainActivity to the SecondaryActivity using intents, but how would you do that Vise Versa. Here is the code that I am using, I just don't know where to put the Recieving classes code.

In my SecondActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
String TimeValue = ("00:00:00");
intent.putExtra("TimeValue", TimeValue);
startActivity(intent)
```

and This is the code that I am not sure where to put so it doesn't crash when the app starts

```
String intent = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TimeValue");
TextView timeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
timeText.setText(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `MainActivity` won't always be created with an intent coming from `SecondActivity`. It will also be created just when the app is launched.

You need to make sure that `extras` actually exists before trying to get extras from it! It could be null!

So this should be in your onCreate method, after you inflate the view.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

String intentString;
if(extras != null) {
    intentString = extras.getString("TimeValue");
} else {
    intentString = "Default String";
}
TextView timeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
timeText.setText(intentString);
```

I also highly recommend that you change the name of your String to "intentString" instead of "intent." The name "intent" is typically used for actual `Intent` objects, not the `String` that you get out of the `Intent`. So naming it "intentString" makes things more readable for other developers.

Comment: So what would that look like

Comment: @LeytonTaylor edit your current code into the question, and show me the stack trace of the error, and I'll tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pass data back from SecondActivity to the MainActivity, then use `startActivityForResult` instead.

Once you have launched your SecondActivity and ready to pass the data back to the MainActivity, create a new Intent and use `SecondActivity.setResult(resultCode, Intent);`. Then call finish, to finish the SecondActivity.

Now, in your MainActivity, you will get a call to `onActivityResult()` which will give you the Intent you passed in the SecondActivity as a data parameter.

You can look at this link for more info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html